# will pthread_exit() closes the opened files too?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, pthread-exit

i have opened a file in the thread and terminated the thread using pthread_exit() routine. Will it closes the opened files too?

Answer (score 2):

No. `pthread_exit()` doesn't close any open files.

It only releases thread-specific resources. File descriptors are process-wide and any file that you opened in a thread will remain opened and you'll have a resource leak if you call `pthread_exit()` before closing the file.

Comment: And don't be tempted to call fcloseall() either in your thread!